# Getting error while building SpringAndroid project

Tags: android, spring

Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.2: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-parent:pom:21 in http://repo.springsource.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of springrepo1 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

```
 <mirror>
      <id>springrepo1</id>
      <name>Intranet Maven2 Repository</name>     
      <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url> 
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute:

`mvn clean -U install`

The `-U` tag will force an update to maven repository.